# OSError: Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Cipher._raw_ecb' on Apache mod_wsgi CentOS 8

Tags: python, django, apache, centos

I'm trying to run a django project on an apache server. The django server runs fine on its own but fails when running through mod_wsgi. It returns the error as follow :

```
OSError: Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Cipher._raw_ecb': Trying '_raw_ecb.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': /home/user/django/centos_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Cryptodome/Util/../Cipher/_raw_ecb.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: failed to map segment from shared object, 
Trying '_raw_ecb.abi3.so': /home/user/django/centos_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Cryptodome/Util/../Cipher/_raw_ecb.abi3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, 
Trying '_raw_ecb.so': /home/user/django/centos_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Cryptodome/Util/../Cipher/_raw_ecb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked that the file were there. I checked Python home variable and tried to import Crypto.Cipher from the python interpreter(which worked). Everything seems fine.

I tried to compile pycryptodome from source but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem (I'm on Gentoo-Linux) with flask.
Reason were different versions of Python in the virtual environment and mod_wsgi compiled against.
You can see the version of mod_wsgi when you restart apache and look into the error_log, something like

```
AH00163: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1i PHP/7.2.34 mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

shows the version Python mod_wsgi was compiled against.
My virtual environment used Python 3.7 while mod_wsgi was on 3.8 .

Comment: I did a work around by going with nginx which had a lot less problems, but going to check your response as answer.